# Sorting a multi-dimensional Array by value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array and I want to sort it (ASC)?

```
$stand_array[$player_name][$player_points] = $player_rank;
```

**print_r**

```
Array
(
[Player1] => Array
    (
        [50] => 5.7
    )

[Player2] => Array
    (
        [40] => 4.2
    )

[Player3] => Array
    (
        [30] => 3.7
    )

[Player4] => Array
    (
        [20] => 2.3
    )

[Player5] => Array
    (
        [10 => 1.5
    )

[Player6] => Array
    (
        [60] => 6.3
    )
)
```

Would you like to help me to solve this array on $player_rank (ASC)?

NB: I tried this function, but it did not work:

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
return $a[$player_rank] - $b[$player_rank];
}
usort($myArray, 'sortByOrder');
```

Comment: Did you use sql to generate the array? or what did you used to

Comment: I did not generate it with sql otherwise would be easy to sort it. I created the array stand_array with array $player_points and array $player_rank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$player_rank` is not visible from the `sortByOrder` function scope. Also, the indexes is different in each player array, so you need to access it like this:

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) 
{ 
    $a = end($a);
    $b = end($b);

    if ($a == $b) 
    {
       return 0;
    }

    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($myArray, 'sortByOrder');
```

And if you want to save keys in  `$myArray` then you must use the `uasort` function instead of `usort`.